# Trying to connect a comboBox in word to a database in Access using Visual Basic

Tags: database, vba, ms-access, combobox, vsto

I've been working on this for the past 6 hours and I'm getting a frustrating error. For now, I want to add a combo box into my blank word document and populate it with a data from a field in a table I created in Access. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 as my IDE and the Word 2013 Document Template.

***ERROR***

`An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in WordInvoice.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed.`

**My Database Table**

`ID  Employee    Amount
1   Danny   $100.00
2   Andy    $200.00
3   Dixon   $50.00
4   James   $250.00`

**MY CODE**

```
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Public Class ThisDocument
    Private Sub ThisDocument_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
        Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
        Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
        cnn.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" &
                 "Data Source=C:\Users\Danny\Documents\Employee Records1.accdb")
        rst.Open("SELECT Employee FROM Payroll;", cnn, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic)
        rst.MoveFirst()




        Dim ccList As ContentControl
        ccList = ContentControls.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdContentControlType.wdContentControlComboBox)

        ccList.Title = "Select a Employee"
        ccList.SetPlaceholderText(,, "Please Select a Employee")

        Do While Not rst.EOF
            ccList.DropdownListEntries.Add(rst.Fields(0).ToString)
            rst.MoveNext()
        Loop
        rst.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub ThisDocument_Shutdown() Handles Me.Shutdown

    End Sub

End Class
```

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

From some advice I read, I changed by 'Target CPU': from `any PC` to `x86`.  However, this time I received this error from Word upon starting up.

[image]

Comment: setting ccList.RowSource with the Recordset doesn't work anymore ?

Comment: @xum59 not sure what you mean by this. I am new to VB so don't know all the methods for working with Recordset  - can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

Haven't been praticing for a while but, if my memories are correct, this should work :

```
Public Class ThisDocument
    Private Sub ThisDocument_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
        Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
        Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
        cnn.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" &
                 "Data Source=C:\Users\Danny\Documents\Employee Records1.accdb")
        rst.Open("SELECT Employee FROM Payroll;", cnn, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic)
        rst.MoveFirst()

    Dim ccList As ContentControl
    ccList = ContentControls.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdContentControlType.wdContentControlComboBox)

    ccList.Title = "Select a Employee"
    ccList.SetPlaceholderText(,, "Please Select a Employee")
    Set ccList.RowSource=rst
End Sub
...
```

I'm not able to test it, this may require a bit of tweaking... but RowSource have always been the best way (as far as I know) to feed ListBox/ComboBox with DB rows.

This supports a lot of sources like ADO & DAO Recordsets, Arrays...

Comment: `ccclist.RowSource` doesn't seem to be a property of ContentControl  am I missing something?  This although would help me fill in the comboBox with the data from my table in Access - won't solve the `provider cannot be found` error, which I'm still not sure how to solve. All I can find so far is some talk about that provider not working in 64 bit or something, not sure still... I might have to switch the provider to SQL server database and make my table there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the x64 Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable and change your connection string to Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0