# Can SSIS connect with MS Word using VBS?

Tags: vbscript, ssis, ms-word

I'm trying to write a script in VBScript which should open Microsoft Word and edit the text. My problem is:

1. As to connect SSIS with Excel, we can use `"ADODB.Connection"`. I cannot find any connection for MS Word ?
2. As for Excel, we can put the target since row and column can be used. But it MS Word, how do I call the data and put it to location i want.

So basically, the document will be used as template and when the script execute it will call data from SSIS.

For example: profit of every branch for today.

Comment: I think you probably wanted `VBA` rather than `vbscript`?

Comment: This post has an answer for creating a combobox. You didn't specify what type of object in Word you want to create, but it should get you started I think: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32573294/trying-to-connect-a-combobox-in-word-to-a-database-in-access-using-visual-basic

Comment: @Dave not necessarily, early versions of SSIS used "Script Task" which ran VBScript.

Comment: DTS used ActiveX scripting languages, of which VBScript was one. SSIS supported a VB.NET dialect in the 2005 release and 2008/R2 timeframe introduced C# as the second supported language </pedantic>

Comment: Search for posts that use `CreateObject(" , "Word.Application")` in order to discover how to automate Word using any VB-language. Word has no data connection method. That, or you need a library that can work with the Zip package and XML contents of the Word Open XML file format (which seems the more correct approach if this is a server environment).

Comment: Word uses Bookmarks. It also has row column (as Word is ALSO a spreadsheet as in the distance past programs did not talk to each other so one program had to supply all features) but no database driver as most word documents have stuff other than tables. **NB: You are talking about COM which is language independent.**